# What do the <>'s mean in Java declarations and instantiations?

Tags: java

I am new to java and have a question

```
myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

What is `HashMap` and what does it mean when we use `<` `>` for `ArrayList` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) can be considered as array in PHP. `ArrayList` is indexed by number, and `HashMap` is collection of key value pairs - PHP does not differentiate those two situations.

This particular declaration says that there is an `ArrayList` (number indexed array) and all its element are of type `HashMap`. For each `HashMap`, which is a collection of key/value pairs, the keys are of type `String`, and values are of type `Object`.

Comment: +1 for (presumably) checking Autolycus' profile and using a PHP analogy.

Answer (score 6):

It indicates generic type in Java. For instance, if you're using an `ArrayList` as follows

```java
myBooks = new ArrayList<String>();
```

means that what is being stored into the `ArrayList myBook` will be of type String available in Java.

In the following statement

```java
myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

The ArrayList is holding a HasMap with keys of type String and values of type Objects.

---

Similarly, you can make use of `Collection`, `List`, `HashTable` etc with generic types and should always be used with generic types because they can hold any kind of values.

such as

```java
Collection<String> c=new ArrayList<String>();

List<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();

Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

---

You could have simply defined them without genetic types as follows.

```java
Collection c=new ArrayList();

List list=new ArrayList();

Hashtable h=new Hashtable();
```

The compiler will not complain at all in this situation but its always preferable to use generic with them.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of Java generics.

A data structure like `List` or `Map` or `Set` can hold any kind of object.  When you use generics, you tell the compiler exactly what type of object the data structure is holding.

In your case, you've got a `List` of `Maps`.  The `Map` has `String` keys and `Object` values.

Answer (score 3):

All of the above answers are great.

In addition, though, I would like to point out that you should also read up on [Java Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to understand the difference between the compile-time and run-time behaviors of Generics.

You will save yourself a lot of pain by understanding type erasure correctly.